# Joomla 3.0 on Gantry - bootstrap - duplicating the mainmenu for phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0

I am working on a new template using Gantry as a base and need to build a menu in a way to handle a mobile phone. The problem I am having is that the way I modified the default.php file in mod_menu in order to duplicate the menu for a mobile setup also dups the other menus in the site ie. footer menu.

Is there a way I can build out the main menu to be mobile friendly without messing with the footer menu?

Here is a link to the working example I am dealing with. Notice the footer menu acts the same way as the mainmenu whe you scale down to a phone size.

http://www.mniac.com/spymaniac30/

```
<nav class="main <?php echo $class_sfx; ?>"<?php
$tag = '';
if ($params->get('tag_id') != null)
{
    $tag = $params->get('tag_id') . '';
    echo ' id="' . $tag . '"';
}
?> role="navigation">
<ul>
        <?php if ($class_sfx === 'nav-list') : ?>
        <li></li>
        <li class="nav-header"><?php echo $module->title; ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php

    $previous_parent = null;
    foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
        $class = '';
        if ($item->id == $active_id)
        {
            $class .= 'current ';
        }

        if ($item->type == 'alias' &&
                in_array($item->params->get('aliasoptions'), $path)
                || in_array($item->id, $path))
        {
            $class .= 'active ';
        }
        if ($item->deeper)
        {
            $class .= 'deeper ';
        }

        if ($item->parent)
        {
            $class .= 'parent dropdown ';
            $previous_parent = $item->id;
            $item->flink = "#";
        }

        if (!empty($class))
        {
            $class = ' class="' . trim($class) . '"';
        }

        echo '<li id="item-' . $item->id . '"' . $class . '>';

        // Render the menu item.
        switch ($item->type) :
            case 'separator':
            case 'url':
            case 'component':
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' . $item->type);
                break;

            default:
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
                break;
        endswitch;

        // The next item is deeper.
        if ($item->deeper)
        {
            echo '<ul class="jb-nav dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop' . $previous_parent . '">';
        }
        // The next item is shallower.
        else if ($item->shallower)
        {
            echo '</li>';
            echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
        }
        // The next item is on the same level.
        else
        {
            echo '</li>';
        }
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="mobile <?php echo $class_sfx; ?>"<?php
$tag = '';
if ($params->get('tag_id') != null)
{
    $tag = $params->get('tag_id') . '';
    echo ' id="' . $tag . '"';
}
?> role="navigation">
<div id="menu-link"><a href="#">MENU</a></div>
<ul style="display:none;">
        <?php if ($class_sfx === 'nav-list') : ?>
        <li></li>
        <li class="nav-header"><?php echo $module->title; ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php

    $previous_parent = null;
    foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
        $class = '';
        if ($item->id == $active_id)
        {
            $class .= 'current ';
        }

        if ($item->type == 'alias' &&
                in_array($item->params->get('aliasoptions'), $path)
                || in_array($item->id, $path))
        {
            $class .= 'active ';
        }
        if ($item->deeper)
        {
            $class .= 'deeper ';
        }

        if ($item->parent)
        {
            $class .= 'parent dropdown ';
            $previous_parent = $item->id;
            $item->flink = "#";
        }

        if (!empty($class))
        {
            $class = ' class="' . trim($class) . '"';
        }

        echo '<li id="item-' . $item->id . '"' . $class . '>';

        // Render the menu item.
        switch ($item->type) :
            case 'separator':
            case 'url':
            case 'component':
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' . $item->type);
                break;

            default:
                require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
                break;
        endswitch;

        // The next item is deeper.
        if ($item->deeper)
        {
            echo '<ul class="jb-nav dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop' . $previous_parent . '">';
        }
        // The next item is shallower.
        else if ($item->shallower)
        {
            echo '</li>';
            echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
        }
        // The next item is on the same level.
        else
        {
            echo '</li>';
        }
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to edit your core files, always aviod if you can, for obvious reasons ^^

just add another menu module in a "mobile position" so it should be hidden if screen width over X and shown if below.

or since its bootstrapped already: one module for topmenu and one module for the footer

so you end up duplicating modules in the module manager instead of changing code...

simple as that

Comment: When you say "mobile position" do you mean create a new position aside from the navigation position? I was thinking of working with the positions available and targeting the menus with ids... Problem is I'm not sure how to add an id to a menu.

Comment: you can add a position container just below your usual nav in your index.php `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav aka position-X" style="xhtml" /> <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mobile-nav" style="xhtml" />` and adress your module ids for showing/hiding.... or just "toggle-hide" in the same position.

menu-items get ids assigned by joomla, which puts the ids in the id/class of the element....

e.g. `<li id="item-101">...</li>`... but you already had your menu switching to "mobile" version since it was css @media adressed... and what is `"=""` in `<nav role="navigation" "="">`???